# Is it possible to output a list of html pages names with handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Ok so I need to output a list of emails that were sent out. I'm using Zurb's Pannini(handlebars), but I'm not sure how to do it. Is it even possible?

I'm attaching an image of the file structure. The emails are in archive folder from the pages folder, and I need to write the handlebars code on the emails-table.html from the partials folder.

[File Structure Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3l4x.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I found your question as I was searching for a similar problem of iterating through pages to create "featured posts" for a home page.

I don't think that Foundation will do this natively.  There is an {{#each XXX}}} construct in Handlebars/Panini that will iterate through YAML data.

You may be able to solve your particular issue by having your build process create a YAML array from the list of email filenames, store it in the data folder, and then use the {{#each}} technique to use that data to populate your emails-table.html table.